# item controller for Em.CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

I'am trying to use `Em.CollectionView` to render `ArrayController`. Problem that 'itemView' used to render each item has wierd render context (I expected that item will be used as context). But It's not.

Here is my templates. 
**Index template:**

```
{{view Ember.CollectionView content=controller itemViewClass="color"}}
```

**Color template:**

```
<b>content:</b>{{content}} </br>
<b>this:</b>{{this}} </br></br>
```

Here is model router and controller:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'color'
});
```

And result is:

```
content:red,yellow,blue  this:<App.IndexController:ember209> 

content:red,yellow,blue  this:<App.IndexController:ember209> 

content:red,yellow,blue  this:<App.IndexController:ember209>
```

Full example -- http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aZiciYOc/4/edit
How to set item controller properly?

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
{{each controller itemView="color"}}
```

Instead of:

```
{{view Ember.CollectionView content=controller itemViewClass="color"}}
```

will work.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aZiciYOc/8/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="color">    
 <b>content:</b>{{view.content.model}} </br>
 <b>this:</b>{{this}} </br></br>
</script>
```

Difference is in second line

Comment: yeah I know but found this really wierd